# XJC catalog does not replace local path for schema import

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I have a schema a.xsd which imports b.xsd. I have entry in schema a.xsd as follows :

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.example.com/v1.0"
               schemaLocation="b.xsd"/>
```

I need to use schema b.xsd from a jar(public sdk). So i use a catalog file as follows

```
SYSTEM "b.xsd" "jar:file:example-api-schemas.jar!/schemas/b.xsd"
```

or 
`SYSTEM "b.xsd" "schemas/b.xsd"` in case i have it on local file system.

Since i cannot edit any of these xsd files, i think using catalog is the only last resort. But while generating stub files with help of catalog file not found exception is thrown.
I am using following command to generate files

```
xjc -extension -catalog catalog.cat a.xsd
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be hitting this issue:

https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-942

Or maybe some other XJC peculiarity. Maybe XJC tries to match the resolved local URI of `b.xsd` which will be something like `file:..../b.xsd` - and this does not match with your catalog, naturally.

Try the following:

- Try adding `-nv` to put it XJC into a "non-validating" mode. Sometimes it helps.
- Instead of binding via file location you could try binding via namespace:

  PUBLIC "urn:namespace:of:b" "jar:file:example-api-schemas.jar!/schemas/b.xsd"